# Game trailer feedback?

Tags: feedback, trailer

Hello everyone if you have time could you give my clip a watch and give me any pointers to improve?  Sadly the conversion Vimeo has done has really effected the sound quality for some reason?

Link - http://vimeo.com/20410288

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

hey, nice work!

a few things that come to mind:

a) it seems quite out of sync to me? or is that the vimeo-issue you mentioned?

b) it would be really nice, if you could work out the unique character from each car... what i mean is, that an audi will sound very different to a lamborghini... would be nice to hear this... 
you could also establish those different sounds at the very beginning (the logo-animation) - 4 cars - 4 colors.

c) have you tried adding something for the changing environment-colors? i think some subtle sounds could make them much more noticable...

hope this helps :)

Comment: @Manuel - Thanks for your thoughts. I think the out of sync is the vimeo thing as it seems okay when I play it solely on my system. Thanks for bringing up the character of the cars, I will try and warp them to make them closer to the original car sounds. I will look into the colour idea, very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds pretty gnarly to me!